# Controlling S4 function resolution in R

Tags: r, plot, r-s4

I'm trying to create an S4 package with a function 'plot' that would then use heatmap.2 (package 'gplots') to plot the contents of my object.  Unfortunately, the dendrograms of the heatmap don't plot and I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘plot’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘plot’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

This definitely happens because there's an internal call to a method plot on numeric data, presumably when plotting dendrograms, and R can't tell whether I mean the plot function that I'm calling from or the default.  However, I already try to avoid this situation by declaring my plot function as follows:

```
##assign generic plot to plot.missing as the default function
##then create a plot for the current object (default has to be saved first!)
if (!exists("plot.missing")) plot.missing <- plot
setGeneric("plot", function(object, ...) standardGeneric("plot"));
setMethod("plot", "missing", function(object, ...) plot.missing());
##now it's safe to create a custom predict method

setMethod(f = "plot", 
          signature(object = "REFSEnsembleLite"),
          definition = function(object, type = 'significance', ...) {
```

I'm not an expect on S4, but I thought this would allow the default plot function to be found.

Oh yes, a final detail: heatmap.2 works outside of the plot function of my S4 object, so I think this has definitely something to do with the fact that I'm calling from within a function called 'plot'.